# How can I extract HTML embedded in RTF using Python?

Tags: python, html, outlook, exchange-server, rtf

I'm trying to extract the HTML email bodies from Outlook msg files. I've successfully converted them to eml/standard RFC 822 files using [email-outlook-message-perl](https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl), but the body of the emails are HTML [wrapped in RTF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159831(v=exchg.80).aspx). Here's an example snipit:

```
{\*\htmltag96 <div class="EduText" style="padding:2px;border-width:1px;background-color:#DEE5ED;border-color:##FAFAFA;border-style:solid;">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 {\*\htmltag64}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf{\f4\fs24\htmlrtf0 \'cd\'d5\'e0\'c1\'c5\'b9\'d5\'e9\'ca\'e8\'a7\'e4\'bb\'b7\'d5\'e8 john.smith\htmlrtf\f0}\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag116 <br>}\htmlrtf \line
\htmlrtf0
```

Is there a way to get the the HTML content, without all of the RTF crud?

Comment: have you tried [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, it does not strip out the RTF markup.

Comment: Is it valid `RTF`? Load into e.g. Word and save as Text.

Answer (score 1):

This is a few years old back thread, but this might be helpful for one who is new to TNEF and he is in similar situation...

If you are a Linux user, then you could extract the html content from rtf file using Linux command line tool unrtf

**unrtf message.rtf**

This will give you the output with html content.

If you want to redirect it into a file, then could try
**unrtf message.rtf > message.html**

Hope this helps...

**-Suresh**

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is using [TNEF (Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815562.aspx). So I think you need to search for a TNEF Phyton implementation like:

- [tnefparse](https://github.com/koodaamo/tnefparse)

Comment: tnefparse is helpful to parse the winmail.dat file and sometimes tnefparse would give us the rich text format files as part of processing. In that scenario, we have to use some tools to extract the HTML from RTF content. For example, we can use unrtf tool to fetch the HTML content.